Which dash to use to display the text Arist - Album in a music player?
I'm coding a music player and I want to show the current song information in a status bar, like ArtistName - AlbumName.  I'm unsure which dash to use.  I was thinking of using an em dash, since a page on the Miriam Webster website (https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/em-dash-en-dash-how-to-use) says "A dash often precedes the name of an author or source at the end of a quoted passage", but I'm not sure. If relevant, I'm based in the UK.

Pick the one that is clearest in whichever font you've chosen for your application. No one is going to be nitpicking your punctuation in a music app.

It's opinion. IMO today any use of the em or en dash that does not have surrounding spaces looks ugly. The linked site advises using one of them instead of a hyphen, which I don't like.

This has nothing to do with grammar. Window titles aren't sentences.

@WeatherVane okay I see, I'll go with either an em dash with a space on each side or a hyphen then

I would avoid a hyphen (which has no surrounding space) in this context.

I tried out a few styles and the em dash with a space looks the best, I'll go with that. Thanks @WeatherVane.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not actually about usage. The dash character is being used as a kind of decoration rather than semantically as punctuation. Any character could work.

@Andy It's disturbing that your CV doesn't show.

@EdwinAshworth ~~~Curriculum vitae? Sorry, I don't follow~~~ Ohhh, close-vote. Hm, it says I retracted it. That certainly wasn't intentional...

Spurious vote-squelching?

@EdwinAshworth Looking at the history, the question was reopened. Afaik, that should "reset" my votes, but it looks like instead it had the effect of retracting it.

I'd be curious to hear the thoughts of those who voted to reopen; seems to me if it's worth reopening it's worth answering...

@EdwinAshworth Oh, doing my homework, yes, that's how it works. "Each individual user may cast at most one close vote and one reopen vote per question."

It's a duplicate, but it's kind of off-topic and will depend on non-linguistic factors like character sets and aesthetics.

Hi @StuartF yes I think that is close enough, I clicked that it is similar on the popup.
